# How to implement file Download button in Next.js? (window is not defined)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I know 'window' or 'document' objects are not recognizable in React component before component mounts.

I'm trying to make a download button which receive processed excel file from the backend server. Before I'm using React I used to implement like this...

```
 <button onclick="download()">Download</button>
    <script>
        function download() {
            const URL = 'http://dynamic-link.com/sample.xlsx'
            window.location.href = URL
        }
    </script>
```

However, in Next.js or React, window object is not recognizable so I had to do the other way.
**Download URL is dynamic so I won't use next.config.js**

pages/index.tsx

```
//...
const handleDownloadExcel = () => {
    router.push('/download')
  }
//...
return(
//...
      <button onClick={() => handleDownloadExcel()}>Download!</button>
//...
```

pages/download.tsx

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const DownloadPage = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    useEffect(() => {
        //I will pass this URL variable by props later on.
        const URL = 'http://dynamic-url.com/sample.xlsx'
        window.location.href = URL;
        router.push('/')
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
        </>
    )
}

export default DownloadPage;
```

Now I managed to download a file from server but it doesn't seem right. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the window object in next js like this :

```
    <script>
        function download() {
            const URL = 'http://dynamic-link.com/sample.xlsx'
            if (typeof window !== "undefined"){
              window.location.href = URL
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the file-saver package to download our file.

To install it, run:

```
npm i file-saver
```

Then we can call the **saveAs** function from the package by writing:

```
import React from "react";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";

export default function App() {
  const saveFile = () => {
    saveAs(
      "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf",
      "example.pdf"
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={saveFile}>download</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The first argument is the URL to download and the 2nd argument is the file name of the downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the script above. It solved the issue. I also found that in NextJS copying the file into /public/download/ prevents the - HEAD https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf net::ERR_FAILED 200 bug.

And changing "example.pdf" to the intended file name prevents the downloaded file from being named “download.pdf” by default.